# Tasklist using xp_cmdshell

Tags: sql-server, xp-cmdshell, tasklist

I want to know how i will use the tasklist cmd that will output the imagename plus the hostname

i have thus syntax but could not combine the result into one.

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'tasklist /fi "imagename eq notepad.exe"';
```

plus hostname

Comment: What is `plus hostname`? is it trying to be part of the syntax that you are running or an explanation of what you want? The hostname will always be the SQL Server so that is `SELECT @@SERVERNAME`. If you want the hostname to appear as another column, tell us exactly which version of SQL you are running as that has a bearing on the approach

Comment: Hello Nick, yes plus is my explanation on what to expect in the result, my version is mssql 2012 and 2008 r2, i need to insert the result in a table. i have two columns, output and servername. thnaks for your reply

Comment: You first need to _connect_ to a single SQL Server to run this. What mechanism are you using to run this? You'll need to run it against many servers.

Comment: by the way i'm using orchestrator. so i'm having a hard time incorporate the 2 sql server and microsoft orchestrator

Comment: I've never used Orchestrator but I guess its some kind of job management system. Why don't you post a specific issue and we can try and address it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you what you want:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (capture VARCHAR(5000))

INSERT @T
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'tasklist /fi "imagename eq notepad.exe"'; 

INSERT INTO dbo.[N4FO_OpenGUIOutput] (Output,system) 
SELECT capture, @@SERVERNAME as host FROM @T WHERE capture IS NOT NULL
```

But you have to actually connect to the SQL Server to run it so you'll already need to know the host name to connect to.

Comment: hi nick sorry i'm away for a couple of days, here is my script and having some errors

insert into ControlDB.[dbo].[N4FO_OpenGUIOutput] (Output,system)
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'tasklist /fi "imagename eq notepad.exe"'; 
SELECT  @@SERVERNAME     

and here is my error 


Msg 213, Level 16, State 7, Procedure xp_cmdshell, Line 1
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Comment: Yes. That isn't the script I posted and it is not valid. I will update my script with this new information about table `[N4FO_OpenGUIOutput]` that you've just mentioned

Comment: thanks nick, will wait for your update. thanks a lot

Comment: If this question was of assistance please mark as correct.

Comment: hi nick yes the answer is correct. how do i mark it as correct?